# Scrollable TextView between views

Tags: android

I have TextView (green A) between 2 views.
[image: aa]
Normally I want the B view to appear below A view. But when the TextView's content will be big enough that the B view will meet the bottom of the screen, I want to be able to scroll that 'excessive' A's content. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution but forgot to post it here. So, to achieve this, we need to somehow force a ScrollView's measurement to take place after other views' measurements in a layout. And we can do it by setting layout_weight attribute in ScrollView. So basically, our layout should look like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

     <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
    </ScrollView>


    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by many methods, i will list 3:

Put A and B views inside a ScrollView.
Put A inside a ScrollView.
To scroll the 'excessive' A's content, search on google and use an ScrollableTextView.

Comment: None of these methods applies to my exact problem. Check my answer